# jQuery handle client side event of ASP.NET RadioButtonList

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to run some Javascript code when the selected value of an ASP.Net RadioButtonList is changed, using a jQuery event handler; specifically I want to enable/disable a RequiredFieldValidator on a TextBox (depending on the selected value of the RadioButtonList).. But when I click one of the items in the RadioButtonList (changing its value), nothing is happening.

Here's the Javascript code:

```
var rbAuth = "<%= rbServiceHours.ClientID %>";
var vRespName = "<%= vRespNameReq.ClientID %>";
var vRespTitle = "<%= vRespTitleReq.ClientID %>";
var tbxRespName = "<%= tbxRespName.ClientID %>";
var tbxRespTitle = "<%= tbxRespTitle.ClientID %>";
$('#' + rbAuth + " > input").click(function () {
  if (($('#' + rbAuth).find('input:checked').val()) == 'Yes') {
    $('#' + vRespName).attr('enabled', 'true');
    $('#' + vRespTitle).attr('enabled', 'true');
    $('#' + tbxRespName).addClass("required");
    $('#' + tbxRespTitle).addClass("required");
  }
  else {
    $('#' + vRespName).attr('enabled', 'false');
    $('#' + vRespTitle).attr('enabled', 'false');
    $('#' + tbxRespName).removeClass("required");
    $('#' + tbxRespTitle).removeClass("required");
  }
});
```

This is, of course, inside `$(document).ready( function() {});`

Here's the corresponding ASP.Net markup:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbServiceHours" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
  CssClass="required" ValidationGroup="valIncident" TabIndex="31">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Y" Text="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="N" Text="No"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>

<asp:TextBox ID="tbxRespName" runat="server" MaxLength="50" TabIndex="29">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vRespNameReq" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<br />Please enter the caregiver's name."
  CssClass="validationError" ControlToValidate="tbxRespName" ForeColor="White"
  BackColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="valIncident" 
  Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:TextBox ID="tbxRespTitle" runat="server" MaxLength="50" TabIndex="29">
</asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="vRespTitleReq" runat="server" ErrorMessage="<br />Please enter the caregiver's title."
  CssClass="validationError" ControlToValidate="tbxRespTitle" ForeColor="White"
  BackColor="Red" SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="valIncident" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Edit: Here's the rendered HTML:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxRespName" type="text" maxlength="50" 
  id="ctl00_MainContent_tbxRespName" tabindex="29" />
<span id="ctl00_MainContent_vRespNameReq" class="validationError" 
  style="color:White;background-color:Red;display:none;"><br />Please enter the 
  caregiver's name.</span>
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbxRespTitle" type="text" maxlength="50" 
  id="ctl00_MainContent_tbxRespTitle" tabindex="30" /><br />
<span id="ctl00_MainContent_vRespTitleReq" class="validationError" 
  style="color:White;background-color:Red;display:none;"><br />Please enter the 
  caregiver's title.</span>
```

Comment: Mind posting the rendered HTML to?

Comment: You should use more ASP in your javascript, looks good !

Comment: You should really look into caching your ASP variable names...

Comment: @adeneo - That comment seems like completely gratuitous and unnecessary sarcasm. Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @maccettura - I'm not really sure what you mean, can you provide an example? Though I don't think it would have any bearing on the solution to the problem I'm having.

Comment: Capture the ASP ClientID into a variable, then execute jQuery from that.

Comment: @maccettura OK, I've done what you suggested (question updated), yet I'm still not getting anything when I click on the radio buttons.

Comment: Could it be that you have `.val() == "Yes"` but you have `Value="Y"` in the `RadioButtonList`?

Comment: You also need to show the rendered HTML for the `RadioButtonList` as I guess the jQuery isn't finding the controls to attach the event to.  Have you tried putting in a simple `alert` into the start of the `click` function to confirm it's going into it?

Comment: @freefaller This is really embarrassing, but the "Yes" vs. "Y" was the problem. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome... I'll make that an answer for you

Comment: @timbck2 I'm sorry, I didn't mean that your problem was the caching.  It was more a comment about your code/best practices.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727376/jquery-handle-client-side-event-of-asp-net-radiobuttonlist#comment27629440_18727376)...

The problem is that you're checking for `.val() == "Yes"` but your `RadioButtonList` item has `Value="Y"`.